# Decrypt TLS https data traffic

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, packet-sniffers, tls1.2

I have implemented a Java network packet sniffer similar to that proposed by 
http://www.freeproject.co.in/source/Network-Packet-Sniffer.aspx?pf=Java&t=web or
http://packetsnifferusingjpcap.blogspot.it/

Now I would like to decrypt the data stream coming from an https, in an attempt to do so I set the variable SSLKEYLOGFILE, in this way the browser will write the values used to generate TLS session keys out to a file indicated by this variable see https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Psst+Your+Browser+Knows+All+Your+Secrets/16415/

As it is explained in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format

The file indicated by SSLKEYLOGFILE is a series of lines. Comment lines begin with a sharp character ('#'). Otherwise the line takes one of these formats.

```
RSA <space> <16 bytes of hex encoded encrypted pre master secret> <space> <96 bytes of hex encoded pre master secret>

CLIENT_RANDOM <space> <64 bytes of hex encoded client_random> <space> <96 bytes of hex encoded master secret>
```

How can I use the SSL / TLS secrets log file in order to decrypt network packages in a java code ?

Comment: If you have control on network (to install your proxy) and client machine (to install your own CA cert), better try MITM attack.

Comment: @user1516873 could you  explain how to do ? the evnironment is: 
1) my browser is connected to a site that transmits data using the ssl protocol, although on a port other than 443 
2) I have a sniffer that intercept all no encrypted traffic

Is possible to put a proxy betwen encrypted data (browser) and sniffer, so that the sniffer receives decrypted data ?

P.S. using wireshark I'm able to decrypt the data

Comment: It seems unlikely that wireshark would be able to decrypt data over tls, unless my understanding of how tls works is flawed.

Comment: @Sam Sun see this: https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Psst+Your+Browser+Knows+All+Your+Secrets/16415/

Comment: @famedoro MITM - Man In The Middle, you disguise youself as server and got all data sended by client decrypted. But you need 1) act like proxy 2) insert your own root CA certificatete in client browser. For example - Fiddler https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_%28software%29

Answer (score 1):

Since wireshark already implements all necessary logic, you could just pipe your captured data through [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), and parse the output text back into your application.

You could possibly also do it on your own with the help of a crypto library like [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/documentation.html), but it would be a lot of effort, because you would still have to parse the handshake and everything (The SSLKEYLOGFILE contains just the *really* secret bits, a lot of context is still needed to successfully decrypt traffic!).

Comment: Thanks for your response: I had already thought about this possibility (see https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/48767/tshark-parameter-for-filtering-by-given-ip-and-decode-it-using-ssl ), but I do not know how redirection on a file, all decrypted packets from a fixed IP address. Wireshark decrypt only packets after giving "Follow stream" on a particular packet ( correct me if I'm wrong ), while I would like to decode all packets from a given Ip.

Comment: One answer to your tshark question indicates you just have to tell it which ports to decrypt as ssl. If you have the captured packets it should be trivial in Java to check if their source ip ist the one you are interested in, and if yes, look up the port number.

Comment: Of course this means calling tshark at least once for every new port you encounter, but you for convenience you could even call it once for each tcp connection (Again tracking those in your own code).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, you need to create a TLS client. There are a number of good TLS Java libraries available but you might give the JRE bundled Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) a try before trying the third-party tools. JSSE has nice integration to the rest of the Java crypto tools. To get started, you can use [these JSSE samples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/samples/).

If the APIs in the default JSSE implementation don't suit your needs, take a look at these two good open-source TLS libraries for Java:

- [The Legion's Bouncy Castle](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java)
- [Amazon's s2n](https://github.com/awslabs/s2n)

Once you have decrypted the packets you still, of course, need to handle the HTTP traffic. To do that you can hand the packets back to the browser, or another HTTP client library.

**Note 1**: the ephemeral secrets created during the TLS handshake are good for only the specific TLS session. Collecting these ephemeral secrets does not allow you to create a general proxy, as [Mallory would want to mount a generic man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) but it does, however, give you access to the TLS-encrypted information, so if Alice is signing into her bank, Alice's username and password would be part of the TLS-encrypted data that is now available. This is one reason, username-password schemes have poor security characteristic even if Alice creates a "strong" password.

**Note 2**: in TLS, Alice has to **trust** her TLS client, i.e., when Alice uses public terminal, Alice is *trusting* that her browser is Google's version of Chrome, not [Chuck's or Malloy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) version of Chromium.

**Note 3**: in TLS, Alice has to **trust** that only Bob has access to Bob's private key when she connects to Bob's server. If Chuck captures Bob's private key, then Chuck can proxy Bob's site without Alice noticing (and, sadly, it often takes Bob a *long time* to notice) -- unfortunately, there are a number of IT operational weaknesses that make this particular scenario relatively easy but that's not technical attack on TLS itself.

**Note 4**: Mallory could use the [Key Compromise Impersonation attack](https://kcitls.org/) as a general man-in-the-middle technical attack on TLS, if the client is vulnerable and the server obliges; KCI is mostly mitigated at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com) (30 day free), it is written in Java, will allow inspection of https traffic unencrypted and is much more friendly than WireShark. But Charles Proxy only handles http/https, wireshark is more general.